# Isomorphism of Galois Groups

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

$E$ is the splitting field for $f(x)=x^3-2$ and $K := E(\sqrt 5)$. We want to show that $G=\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z_2} \times S_3$.

To do this, we know that $K$ has subfields $E$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 5)$, which are Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, there are restriction maps given as $$r_E: G\rightarrow \text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}) ~~~ \text{and} ~~~ r_F: G\rightarrow \text{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$$

We know $\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_3$ and $\text{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z_2}$ so it suffices to show that the map $G \rightarrow \text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}) \times \text{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$ given by $\sigma \mapsto (r_E(\sigma),r_F(\sigma))$ is an isomorphism.

I am not sure how I would go about showing that this map defines an isomorphism. Any suggestions?

Comment: By a counting argument, it's enough to show that it's injective

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little further please? I am not sure what you mean here.

Comment: You know that $K(\sqrt 5)$ is a Galois extension of degree $12$. So its Galois group has order $12$. So to show that your map is a bijection, you just need to show that it's injective.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean $E(\sqrt 5)$? Also, I am struggling to show injectivity. If we take two maps $\phi$ and $\psi$ in $G$ and we know that these are determined by where they send roots. We assume their restrictions over $E$ and over $F$ are the same. I am not sure where to go from here?

Comment: The key point to proving injectivity is that $K$ is the compositum of $E$ and $F$ - i.e. it is the smallest field containing both fields. Thus, if an automorphism $\sigma$ fixes $E$ and $F$, then it fixes $K$.